# C# Pause a working thread from the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

So, I want to pause a working thread from the main thread and if I decide to, I want to be able to resume it's activity. Before, I used `myThread.Suspend()` and `Resume()` but it has become *deprecated* and it's *not recommended* to use it anymore.

Could any of you give me an *alternative* please?
Thanks!

Comment: the modern way is to redesign the thread to use synchronization objects and then controlling the thread by locking a mutex from the main thread

Comment: There's a reason for that warning. *Pausing a thread* is deprecated. What are you trying to do and why would you want to pause a thread? That was always a bad design. You can use an event to signal that processing should be stoped. Far better though is to rewrite your code so that you don't need to pause at all.

Comment: From MSDN: **Because Thread.Suspend and Thread.Resume do not rely on the cooperation of the thread being controlled, they are highly intrusive and can result in serious application problems like deadlocks (for example, if you suspend a thread that holds a resource that another thread will need).**

Comment: I'd personally recommend using either async / await for I/O intensive tasks, or using the BackgroundWorker class.  I have a monitoring application that uses multiple BackgroundWorkers monitoring database connections, and I've found it to be far superior to manual thread management.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use `ManualResetEvent` or `AutoResetEvent` object. Thread awaiting the signal will block until something will call Set() on event object.

Of course this applies only if you control the loop executing in worker thread.

```
private ManualResetEvent runningWork = new ManualResetEvent(true);

public void Main()
{
    //

    // suspend
    runningWork.Reset();

    // resume
    runningWork.Set();

    //
}

public void Work()
{
    // long task
    while (!stop)
    {
        runningWork.WaitOne(/* optional timeout */);

        //worker task
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the work that the thread does, that's why I asked for something that I could use to pause it from the outside.

Comment: @dizzyOWNZ that's precisely why you shouldn't do this. You don't know what will happen if you do. That's why `Suspend()` and `Resume()` have those warnings. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I use it in a installer, when the exit confirmation window shows up, the thread is being paused, if the user confirms to exit, the threads gets aborted, if he decides to continue, the thread is resumed.

Comment: You know, if one confirms to exit you should support this behaviour and, for example uninstall files which have already been unpacked? You just have to have a control.

Comment: That is not what I meant, the uninstalling behavior works fine, the fact that in between installing and aborting the install and uninstalling the unpacked files, there is this block of code in which I pause the thread to see if the user confirms if he wants to cancel the installation process.

Comment: Calling an event `suspended`, and *setting* it to mean "resume" is one of the most confusing things I've seen this year. "I have to wait for the suspended event to be set before I can resume." That there's a huge WTF.

Comment: Haha yeah, I wanted to make it readable as &quot;if suspended then wait&quot;. I can&#39;t figure out proper name for event that make sense and tell the state

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point. The reason that `Thread.Pause` and `Thread.Resume` are deprecated is that using them can lead to a whole host of problems. Calling `Thread.Pause` pauses a thread in its tracks, regardless of what the thread is doing. It might be holding a lock. It will continue to hold that lock for as long as it's suspended. It might be in the middle of copying a file, doing a database update, performing a time-critical task, updating shared data structures, etc. Pausing a thread during any of those, or many other tasks, can leave your program, a database, the file system, or possibly even the operating system in an inconsistent state. If you then abort the thread, you make that inconsistent state permanent.

In other words, Don't Do That.

If you want the ability to pause and resume a thread, you need to code the thread so that it knows it can be paused. You need to make it cooperate in pausing. So instead of stopping a thread in its tracks, you tell the thread that you want it to stop at its earliest safe opportunity.

The simplest way I know of to do that is with a [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx). The idea here is that you initialize the event in the set state. When you want the thread to pause, you clear the event. Then you set it again when you want the thread to resume. For example:

```
ManualResetEvent OkayToContinue = new ManualResetEvent(true);

// in your main thread

Thread myThread = CreateWorkerThread(...); // however you do that.

// pause the thread . . .
OkayToContinue.Reset();

// do whatever you want to do while the thread is suspended

// And then restart the thread
OkayToContinue.Set();
```

And in the worker thread:

```
while (!done)
{
    // make sure it's safe to continue
    OkayToContinue.WaitOne();

    // do next step . . .
}
```

Now, if you want the thread to terminate, you typically use a [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.CancellationToken.aspx). To do that, you add this to your main program:

```
CancellationTokenSource CancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Typically, you'd pass the `CancelTokenSource.Token` to the thread, so that it doesn't have access to the CancelletionTokenSource object, but for this example, I'll access it through the parent object.

```
// in your thread proc
do
{
    // do next step
    // Then check to see if paused or canceled
    OkayToContinue.WaitOne();
} while (!done && !CancelToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested);
```

The key here is that you're not pulling the rug out from under the thread. Instead, you're telling the thread to shut down gracefully.

Answer (score -1):

```
private BackgroundWorker _bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

public void Main(string[] args)
{
    _bgWorker.DoWork += _bgWorker_DoWork;

    // We want to be able to cancel our installation, for whatever reason.
    _bgWorker.SupportsCancellation = true;

    _bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void _bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!_bgWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        // Do things for your install here.
    }

    // Display your dialog asking if they'd like to continue.
    if (!userWantsToContinue)
    {
        // Do rollback logic here.
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do the rest of your install.
    }
}
```

This is kind of a rough thrown together example of using a BackgroundWorker to do this, instead of a separate thread that you'll have to manage.  The BackgroundWorker also has the added benefit of reporting progress with an event, and reporting thread work completion with an event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx